# Ceil function using limited set of arithmetic operators

Tags: algorithm, math

Is it possible to calculate a ceiling (e.g `ceil(2.12) = 3`) with only a few arithmetic operations available: `* - + /` 
I.e. without casting and other software tricks, only using division/mul/sub/addition and comparison operators?

Clarifications:

- Complexity is important, but I will be glad to hear any solutions.
- Modulus not available.
- Values are positive.
- Operations are not rounding.
- By software tricks I meant mod, bit level manipulations, etc.

Basically I have a system which allows assigning expressions to variables where expression can contain only the above 4 arithmetic operation, comparisons, and loops. E.g.

var x = if (A * (1.434 + 0.4325)) > 54.4534) then 45.6
    else then 43.435

and I would like to do

var x = CEIL(...)

Comment: Is it a rounding division?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by software tricks? Or for example what is the data type where it is stored and or what is the input and output of the above said operations (+ - * / )

Comment: Is modulus operator available?

Comment: @orom Any complexity requirements? Is `O(log(MAX_VALUE))` operations good enough?

Comment: no, not rounding and values are positive.

Comment: That depends on the language. As far as the underlying basic assembly is concerned all the operations are in integers (and floating point is represented via integers as well)

Comment: If branching/looping is not available, what you want is not possible, since `+-*/` are all continuous functions.

Comment: If branching is allowed but looping isn't, it's impossible as well, because you need to introduce an infinite number of discontinuities.

Comment: This statement in the question does not make sense: “Operations are not rounding.” Then what does 1 divided by 3 return? Unless it returns exactly one-third (and hence neither integers nor binary floating point is in use), then some rounding has occurred, whether rounding to nearest representable floating-point value or rounding down to an integer, or other change in value.

Comment: What does this mean: “all the operations are in integers (and floating point is represented via integers as well)”? Exactly how is 2.12 represented, for example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but don't expect any amazing performance. The simplest algorithm (`th(x)`) is:

```
frac = x;
while(frac<0) frac+=1;
while(frac>=1) frac-=1;

if(frac>0) return x-frac+1;
else return x;
```

You can do better via binary search (`th(log x)`):

```
lower = 0;
upper = 0;
if(x>0){
  upper = 1;
  while (x > upper) upper *= 2;
}else if(x<0){
  lower = -1;
  while (x > lower) lower *= 2;
}

while(upper-lower > 1){
  //mid is guaranteed to be integer, since the upper-lower is a power of two
  mid = (upper+lower)/2; 
  if(x > mid) lower = mid;
  else if(x < mid) upper = mid;
  else return mid;
}

return upper; // lower for floor
```

Comment: Wouldn't the first algo yield zero for fractions < 1 and do actually floor for >= 1 or am I misunderstanding something?